# React multiple conditions inside ternary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

is there a way i can do multiple conditions in ternary?

Something like this(doesnt work)

```
<button>
disabled={
prod.stock ? false : true || 
disabledBtn ? true : false}
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, ternary conditions can be chained, but you have to replace the first `true` in your statement with the second condition. So, `disabled={prod.stock ? false : disabledBtn ? true : false}`. However, this can also be shortened to `disabled={!prod.stock || disabledBtn}`

Comment: `disabled={!prod.stock || disabledBtn}`

Comment: As  pointed out your condition can be simplified.  But if you did require multiple ternary's, to make your example do what you expected, you just need to add some brackets.. `disabled={(prod.stock ? false : true) || (disabledBtn ? true : false)}`  Otherwise, JS would be seeing the `||` been part of the `true` before it.  `true || disabledBtn...` and was obviously not what you meant.

Comment: Thanks guys, thats perfect